# The group of rigid motions of an icosahedron.

Tags: group-theory, geometry, finite-groups

> Prove that group of rigid motions of icosahedron is isomorphic to $A_{5}$.

Can you help me to prove this?

What I have done is shown that the order of the group of rigid motions of icosahedron is 60, which is same as $A_5$.

Comment: Show your working so far. It'll both help you and encourage others to help you.

Comment: what i have found is just the order of the group.. nothing more..

Comment: what do you know about the group? Do you know that it is simple?

Comment: yes, A_5 is simple group. so what is the relation of the truth that it is simple and the problem?

Comment: No - not $A_5$. Do you know if the icosahedral group is simple?

Comment: I don't know the structure of the icosahedral group at all.I know just the order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by considering the dodecahedron, which is [dual](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DualPolyhedron.html) to the icosahedron and hence has the same group of symmetries.

There are five cubes that fit inside a dodecahedron in such a way that the rotational symmetries permute these cubes with $3$-cycles.

[image]

But $3$-cycles in $\mathcal{S}_{5}$ generate $\mathcal{A}_{5}$.

I hope that gives you some strong clues :)

Comment: Here's a picture: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/polypics/dodec-cubes-large.jpeg.

Comment: this is very powerful clue! thx a lot

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: You can also work directly with the icosahedron. First inscribe five octahedra within by [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4511012/248217). Then use rotations of the triangular faces to prrmute these.